# jQuery double animate on focus?

Tags: jquery, focus, jquery-animate

Hi I have setup the following jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/a9ugu/2/

I am wondering why I get a double animate event when I use `.focus()`.

Click on the "click me" and the box that appears animates twice ? How can I stop this ?

Thanks

Comment: Using chrome to look at this I only see one? What browser are you using?

Comment: Um i was using Chrome too ? It seems that it adds `50` twice on the first time I click ? Subsequent clicks are then OK but the first click adds 2x ?

Comment: Oh you mean double wide... thats different lol I thought you meant 2 boxes...

Comment: Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/a9ugu/1/

Comment: Well I want to click and focus and just animate 1x not 2x ?

Comment: generally get better cross browser results animating a wrapping element insted of the input

Comment: Actually - here is the fix :) http://jsfiddle.net/k2Xg2/1/ The issue was calling the select AFTER the animation completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working demo** please let me know if I missed anything: http://jsfiddle.net/k2Xg2/ **and** from @Andy : http://jsfiddle.net/k2Xg2/1/ suffices the need.

So issue was call to `.focus` hence +50 on new input box:

Hope it helps,

**Code**

```
var box = $('#box');
$('#me').toggle(function() {
    box.show();
   // box.focus();
}, function() {
    box.hide();
});

//#region Search Box
$('#box').focus(function () {
    $(this).select();
    $(this).animate({ width: '+=50' }, 200);
});
box.blur(function () {
    $(this).width(150);
    $(this).animate({ width: '-=50' }, 200);
});​
```

Comment: Right thanks .... however I want the animate to occur on focus ? Thanks for the post, but this doesnt solve my problem ?

Comment: He is right when you call focus and select is seems that you are calling the animation twice hence the double animation

Comment: @Andy No worries :) Cool so you want `focus` as well? but withough animate for the first time? I might be able to help you out, Cheers @gabeDel good edit :)

Comment: @Andy Although animate will happen on its on course that will not stop animate to work on focus out and blur, cheers

Comment: Actually - here is the fix :) http://jsfiddle.net/k2Xg2/1 The issue was calling the select AFTER the animation completed - I'll give it to you for sort of pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: @Andy lol cooleos :) glad it helped or give you good direction :))

Answer (score 0):

Something is triggering focus() twice - perhaps as it is created the browser focuses on it?

Looks like u only want it to go 150px wide anyway.. so just hardcode it:

http://jsfiddle.net/a9ugu/4/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `+50` just specify the target width like

```
$box.focus(function () {
    $(this).select();
    $(this).animate({ width: '150' }, 200);
});
$box.blur(function () {
    $(this).animate({ width: '100' }, 200);
});​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/a9ugu/7/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my go at this:

```
var box = $('#box');
$('#me').toggle(function() {
    box.show();
    box.focus();
}, function() {
    box.hide();
});

$('#box').focus(function () {
    //$(this).select(); this line was not needed and was somehow causing your double animation
    $(this).animate({ width: '+=50' }, 200);
});
box.blur(function () {
    $(this).width(150);
    $(this).animate({ width: '-=50' }, 200);
});​
```

The only line that I commented out seems to have been calling the focus a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
$(this).attr(width,yourvalue);
```

so that initial value is what you specify 
Also you can use [Fading effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/) at time of focus so that box doesnt appear to be appearing just instantly rather in a smooth way